# How to update data on unrelated components?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom, js

So I have two unrelated components on one page. And when items are added\deleted on the first one they need to be displayed in second  component. I use this: eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
window.location.reload(true); for page reload when data is added\deleted on first component.But it causes some issues. What would you suggest? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about Lightning Platform Events / message Channels ?
Basically the component that needs to get information can "subscribe" to an event fired by the other components where items get added. This [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch)
has the details but if you need a bare bones implementation , i have one [here](https://github.com/sojman007/StanbicIbtcSalesforceDevTest/tree/master/force-app/main/default)